# Can images from another website create cookies on my site?

Tags: html, cookies, cross-domain

I have a static website, it only contains `html` and `css`. No `javascript`, no `php`, no databases. On this site, I'm using images, which I get from image-hosting websites (like imgur).

I've noticed when I visit my website (on Google Chrome at least), if I click the information button next to the URL, it says there are cookies on this site. If I click on the cookies button, it says `The following cookies were set when you viewed this page` and has a list from cookies, including from those sites that I use for image-hosting.

If I delete them, they come back after a while, but not immediately. I'm trying to avoid cookies as the site is very simple. Are they considered part of my site? If so, is there anything I can do, except hosting the images myself?

I always though that if you link to an image directly (as in a link ending in `.png` for example) it would be the same as if you were hosting the image yourself, and there would be no javascript being run (to save cookies).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are they considered part of my site?

That depends on your perspective.

The *browser* doesn't consider them to be part of your site. Cookies are stored on a per-domain basis, so a cookie received in response to a request for an image from `http://example.com` will belong to `http://example.com` and not to your site.

However, for the purpose of privacy laws (such as GDPR) then they are considered part of your site and, if they are used by the third party to track personally identifiable information, you are required to jump through the usual GDPR hoops.

> If so, is there anything I can do, except hosting the images myself?

Not really.

> I always though that if you link to an image directly (as in a link ending in .png for example) it would be the same as if you were hosting the image yourself, and there would be no javascript being run (to save cookies).

Cookies are generally set with HTTP response headers, not with JavaScript.

Comment: This is a great answer, especially since it mentions privacy and GDPR. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever a browser requests a file from a server it automatically forwards any cookie data along with the request. Image Hosting services may use that for different purposes.

> I always though that if you link to an image directly (as in a link ending in .png for example) it would be the same as if you were hosting the image yourself, and there would be no javascript being run (to save cookies).

**So the question is, how to they set these cookies?**

Let's say, you use a simple img tag to load an image from a hoster.

```
<img src="imageHoster.tld/123xyz.png">
```

The site imageHoster.tld can handle that request by redirecting all requests to e.g. requestHandler.php and that file can set the cookie before sending the image with a simple

```
<?
setcookie("cookieName", "whateverValue", time()+3600);
header('content-type: image/png');
...
?>
```

What happens there is actually the same as if you would set the image source like that:

```
<img src="imageHoster.tld/requestHandler.php?img=123xyz">
```

> Are they considered part of my site?

Since these so called third party cookies are set when visiting your site one could consider them as part of your site. To be on the safe side I would at least mention the use of third party services in the data privacy statement.

> If so, is there anything I can do, except hosting the images myself?

Third party cookies can be disabled in the clients browser. But you can't disable them for the visitors of your site. So no, to avoid third parties setting cookies on client browsers visiting your site you can only avoid using their services.